# Adding javascript file as external source in dll project (VS 2005)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to add an external js file in a DLL project in vs2005 but with no success. Based on this link> [Embed JavaScript in Custom ASP.NET Server Controls](http://jasongaylord.com/blog/embed-javascript-in-custom-asp.net-server-controls), here's what I've done so far:

1) Created a `Scripts` folder with the js file in the dll solution.

2) Set the Build Action to `EmbeddedResource`

3) Overwrote my `OnPreRender` method like this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(ByVal e As EventArgs)
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(Me.GetType(), "webControlesUES.Scripts.EnterToTab.js")
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "EnterToTab", "teste()", True)
End Sub
```

4) On my Render method, I've added this:

```
Me.Attributes.Remove("onkeydown")
Me.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", " teste();")
If Me.TextMode = Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode.MultiLine Then
     Me.Attributes.Remove("onkeydown")
End If
```

5) Added this on my `AssemblyInfo.vb`

```
<Assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("webControlesUES.Scripts.EnterToTab.js", "application/x-javascript")>
```

6) Built the solution and added the dll for testing.

But it's not working. Am I forgetting something here?

Comment: does it give you any errors?  I suppose it just doesn't work in the browser. have you looked at the code that is rendered in the browser (ClientSide)?

Comment: what does the HTML look like on the `.asp(x)` page? I am thinking you might be missing the reference to the `.js` file on the HTML that is rendered

Comment: that's what appears in the code (i've changed my function name):

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
testeloks(event)WebForm_AutoFocus('btnEntrar');// -->
</script>
</form>
 </body>
 

</html>

Comment: The javascript file is in my dll project, so it would be referenced there.

Comment: I am thinking that you also want to add the file outside of the .dll as well. do you know what I mean?  like just sitting in a folder on the server. because the client's browser is trying to access something that isn't really there.  the .dll can be accessed by the server but not by the Clientside Browser.

Comment: My html source code has this tag: <script src="/WebResource.axd?d=CGYPE0mLk4U7dncq7jQKoPs1JekyYlVtoVNdYXt2rnblwbBkjb-EwAakdlj7P_53ChtDMDFsdWVv8FT3Fo2cqDBseDg1&amp;t=634604317351482412" type="text/javascript"></script>.

I guess it's from the js file reference in my dll. But the thing is it's still not working. I've tried many different codes but with no success at all.